# delete columns in data frame not in common with another (R)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes with differenth lengths. On is a sample and the other a test sample

```
df1 a b c d ... 
    1 0 0 0
    2 0 0 1

df2 a e b c d ...
    1 1 0 0 0
    2 0 0 0 1
```

How can I delete the columns of df2 not in common with df1 ?
As a result I'm looking for df2 with the same columns as df1 (a, b, c, d ...).
I tried merge() but its not what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you can subset by the column-names like this:

```
df2[, colnames(df1)]
```

If you have column names in df1 not present in df2 you can do

```
df2[, intersect(colnames(df1), colnames(df2))]
```

Edit: forgot a comma

Comment: +1, note that since `data.frame` inherits from list, you can just use `names` instead of `colnames` to save yourself three keystrokes!  You can even save two more by: `df2[names(df1)]` though I probably wouldn't recommend the last one.