# R remove common columns in dataframes

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have 2 dfs (simplified example):

```
    df1 a b c g ... 
        1 0 0 0
        2 0 0 1
```

And

```
    df2 a b d e f ...
        1 1 0 0 0
        2 0 0 0 1
```

I would like to merge the 2 dfs but before joining I would like to remove common columns in df1 and df2. So I would retain columns (c,d,e,f,g) as a and b are common in df1 and df2.

So basically doing the **opposite** of what was answered here:

[delete columns in data frame not in common with another (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628100/delete-columns-in-data-frame-not-in-common-with-another-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using set operations viz. `union` `intersect` and `setdiff` on `names` of both dfs, we may do this

```r
df1 <- read.table(header = T, text = 'a b c g
        1 0 0 0
        2 0 0 1')

df2 <- read.table(header = T, text = 'a b d e f
        1 1 0 0 0
        2 0 0 0 1')

# uncommon column names
x <- setdiff(union(names(df1), names(df2)), intersect(names(df1), names(df2)))

cbind(df1[names(df1) %in% x], df2[names(df2) %in% x])
#>   c g d e f
#> 1 0 0 0 0 0
#> 2 0 1 0 0 1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can start by using the `duplicated` function to work out which column names both data frames have in common. From there, it's just a matter of selecting and binding the columns from each data frame that are *not* on this list.

```
dupes <- c(names(df1), names(df2))[duplicated(c(names(df1), names(df2)))]

df3 <- cbind(df1[, -which(names(df1) %in% dupes)], df2[, -which(names(df2) %in% dupes)])
```

Following your example, this would produce the following data frame, consisting only of the unique columns from each of the others. This is based on the assumption that both data frames have the same number of rows.

```
df3 c g d e f ...
    0 0 0 0 0
    0 1 0 0 1
```